# it is showing me Warning: Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship between `x` and `y` and Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.8 Gb

Tags: r, many-to-many

I am trying to join two datasets flights and tickets by origin and destination, BUt I am getting the following errors

code:

```
merged_data <- inner_join(distinct(flights), distinct(tickets), by = c("ORIGIN", "DESTINATION"))
```

Errors:

> Warning: Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship between `x` and `y`.
> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.8 Gb

what do I need to do now?

I am trying to resolve this problem but I couldn't.
Could anyone help me out with this?

Thank in advance

Comment: Presumably you need additional distinguishing keys, like date/datetime of flight. I presume this is connecting every flight between locations A+B with every ticket between A+B, and so on for every combination of ORIGIN and DESTINATION. If a flight happens hundreds of times/yr, you will gets hundreds of copies of all the related tickets.

Comment: If you run `dput(flights[20,])` and `dput(tickets[20,])` and add the results to your question, this will help find a solution for you. As for the error, this means you do not have enough RAM to hold the result.

Comment: You should FIRST say what you goal might be. Did you really want every flight from any date and any airline with a particular origin matched to any ticket to a particular destination arriving on any date regardless of airline? Might the ticket data base have a flight number to match against ???